# How to generate a network based on an attribute, like people listing which activities they are attending?

Tags: r, networking, graph, igraph

I have a dataset listing on the rows the name of the participant and on the columns their level of involvement in a specific activity. The level of involvement can vary from 0 to 20, with 0 meaning that the participant is not involved at all, while 20 means max involvement. For example, [in this situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ4WB.png), Marc and Paul are connected by Football, Marc and John are connected because of Basketball, Paul and Micheal are connected by Golf, and so on.

---

I have in mind two possible outputs, depending on feasibility:

- a network object where two nodes are connected only if they both have involvement in the same activity
- a network where the nodes (participants) are connected to an activity node

Could you help me? Let me know if it's not clear enough

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including data and your code which can be used to test and verify possible solutions Check out [mre] and [ask]. It's not a good idea to present your data as an image,

Comment: Oh sorry, would simple text be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small example:

Generate the incidence matrix (as rows the individuals, and as columns the activities). This matches the structure of your data.

```
set.seed(345)
inc <- matrix( rbinom(50, 1, p=0.2) , 10, 5)
colnames(inc) <- letters[1:5] # activities
rownames(inc) <- LETTERS[1:10] # individuals
```

For the first network (individuals connected by an edge if in at least one activity) you need to get the data in the proper "from-to" format. Maybe there is a convenience function that does that for you. If not:

```
# generate all combinations of ids
d <- data.frame(t(combn(rownames(inc), 2)), stringsAsFactors = F)

# check how many activities they have in common:
# you can multiply the rows of two individuals and take the sum
# to get the number of activities they have in common
sum_act <- function(x){
  #debug: x <- 1
  sum = sum(inc[ d[x,"X1"],] * inc[ d[x,"X2"],]) 
}
# now apply your function to all entries in the pairs data frame
d$keep <- sapply(1:nrow(d), sum_act)

head(d)
  X1 X2 keep
1  A  B    1
2  A  C    0
3  A  D    0
4  A  E    0
5  A  F    0
6  A  G    0
```

Now you create an igraph object, calculate centralities, plot it etc:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(d[d$keep>0,], directed = F)
plot(g)
```

[image]

A network with both individuals and activities is called a **bipartite network**. For this one you can use the incidence matrix directly:

```
# igraph object
gp <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(inc)

# bipartite graph
plot(gp, layout = layout_as_bipartite,
     vertex.color=c("green","cyan")[V(gp)$type+1])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The thing that determines which network topology to use is what you want to do by building such a network. The two topologies you show can both work in some circumstance, but it depends on the need.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I am still exploring, so I was planning to try both... Could you please suggest roughly what could be the script needed to obtain the two options?

Comment: Try both to do what thing? The structures are designed to use, if you even don't know why you need it, there is no meaning.

Comment: Like, I need to check different measures of centrality and generate some graphical representation